# Owl Carousel data-dot specific element click sends to first slide, but surrounding click sends to appropriate slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel-2

When I am click on the dots within my data-dot nav, the slide seems to reset to the first slide. However, if I click pixels off the `fa-circle`, or the text, it goes to the appropriate slide. I've tried watching the events firing, but I can't seem to find out what is causing that at all.

[Here is a link to my site in progress](http://firkiosk.wpengine.com/museum)

I'm not running anything in particularly difficult, and have been playing with and without using this bit of code:

I call to the slide element with:

```
<div class="item" data-dot ="<span><i class='fa fa-circle'></i></span><span><?php _e( $i['description'], 'firkisok' );?></span>">
  Content item stuff happens here
</div>

(function($) {
  $(function() {

    // Call Vars
    var owl = $('.owl-carousel');

    // Setup owlCarousel
    owl.owlCarousel({
      dots: true,
      dotsData: true,
      center: true,
      autoWidth: true,
      smartSpeed: 500,
    });

    $( '.owl-dot' ).on( 'click', function() {
      owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(this).index(), 300]);
      $( '.owl-dot' ).removeClass( 'active' );
      $(this).addClass( 'active' );
    })
    $( '.owl-dot span .fa-circle' ).on( 'click', function() {
      owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(this).index(), 300]);
      $( '.owl-dot' ).removeClass( 'active' );
      $(this).parent().parent().addClass( 'active' );
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Whether it's active or not, the event still happens the same, clicking `fa-circle` resets the slideshow to slide 1.

Comment: why do you have two event handers for the same task  .owl-dot and .owl-dot .fa-circle?

Comment: And I would use the first handler, wich seems to work. And I would drop the second... Because `.owl-dot` is over the `.fa-circle` anyway.

Comment: Inspecting the elements, you'll see that I  commented them outI merely added them here to show what i've tried so far/

Comment: It should work if you just remove the event handler associated with the `fa-circle` elements. All the clicks would be handled at the `owl-dot` level, which seems to work. I can get that result on your Web site by setting the CSS attribute `pointer-events: none` on each `fa-circle` element.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I don't know why that wouldn't work for me before, but if you give me that as the answer, I can give you the bounty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I apply the CSS attribute `pointer-events: none` to the `fa-circle` elements on your Web page, the carousel works correctly. That tells me that the event handler on these circle elements is not needed and only causes problems. Therefore, you can remove it completely and keep only the event handler on the `owl-dot` elements:

```
$( '.owl-dot' ).on( 'click', function() {
  owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(this).index(), 300]);
  $( '.owl-dot' ).removeClass( 'active' );
  $(this).addClass( 'active' );
})

// Remove this event handler
//$( '.owl-dot span .fa-circle' ).on( 'click', function() {
//  owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(this).index(), 300]);
//  $( '.owl-dot' ).removeClass( 'active' );
//  $(this).parent().parent().addClass( 'active' );
//})
```